# Inconsistent Results from Bing Maps Geocoder

Tags: geocoding, geospatial, bing-maps

I wrote an application that parses a CSV file, extracts addresses and geocodes them using the Bing Maps REST API.  The problem I am having is that if I run the same file multiple times, I get different results.  On the first trial, rows 2 and 6 might return no matches.  On the following trial, rows 2 and 6 will return matches and row 4 might not.  I inspected the HTTP traffic using Fiddler.  My requests are properly formed, every response returns HTTP status code 200 and valid JSON, just some addresses yield results and some don't and the success or failure of a particular address changes from trial to trial.  Can anyone provide any insight?

**UPDATE**

---

Sample Request:

```
GET http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?o=json&adminDistrict=MI&locality=Shelby&postalCode=49455-1299&addressLine=72+South+State+Street&key={MyApiKey} HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.virtualearth.net
```

Sample Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-BM-TraceID: 9b6cfaa0abdb47b7b7e2790900bcddce
X-BM-Srv: BL2M001304, BL2MSNVM001275, BL2MSNVM001299
X-MS-BM-WS-INFO: 0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 22 Feb 2013 15:14:30 GMT

247
{
    "authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials",
    "brandLogoUri":"http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
    "copyright":"Copyright © 2013 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
    "resourceSets":
    [
        {
            "estimatedTotal":0,
            "resources":[]
        }
    ],
    "statusCode":200,
    "statusDescription":"OK",
    "traceId":"9b6cfaa0abdb47b7b7e2790900bcddce|BL2M001304|02.00.83.1900|BL2MSNVM001275, BL2MSNVM001299"
}
0
```

My post on the MSDN Forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bingmapsservices/thread/c7fea1b2-f87e-40c2-a3a6-496989a338b2#b885ca9a-018a-491f-9caa-a00a515cf9a8

Answer (score 5):

**Bing Maps key and rate limitation information**

I'm sure that you're using a Bing Maps key which would be a trial or a basic key. This type of key is rate limited for obvious reasons (on 24h period and with time between the request) and that's the reason why you're getting a blank response without any information regarding the fact that it failed to geocode.

See the Terms of Use regarding the limitations and other restrictions (stress test and hammering are part of it): http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html

So, in order to solve your problem, you should:

- Check the type of key you're using and how many calls you're making on a specific period
- Check the header of the response, it should include a specific header value: `X-MS-BM-WS-INFO` set to 1

See the MSDN about error handling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701703.aspx

If you're not in this case (if you have an enterprise account), reach the technical support so they can officialy get back to you and check the key.

**Additional information:**

Since you're using the geocoder using a CSV, I would highly recommend to use the Bing Maps Spatial Data Service to perform batch geocoding, see the complete information on the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701733.aspx

It will reduce the number of transactions you would make (each geocode dataflow job counts for 1 transaction and can include over 200 000 entities for each file).

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas.  I have an enterprise license so I don't think I have a rate limit.  That being said, my success rate seems to change at different times of day and from one day to the next so I wonder if this just has to do with general load on the Bing Maps server.  I'll keep an eye on the X-MS-BM-WS-INFO header for now and see if that indicates anything.  In the future I'll definitely use batch geocoding but it's not worth it for me to refactor this app so if I can find a work around, that would be preferable.

Comment: X-MS-BM-WS-INFO is always 0 even in the case of the failures described above.  I updated the OP with a sample request and response.

Comment: Since you're an enterprise customer, you should reach the technical support so they can escalate. Please provide the details information (like link to this post) so they can have a traceId and the different information contained in the header.

Comment: @RaySaltrelli - did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same issues.

Comment: @MikeCole - did you try to verify the points we were discussing here? If you are an enterprise account, please contact the support they will help you further

Comment: hi @NicolasBoonaert , I am using the Spatial services Dataflow API to Geocode addresses. After we submit the job it returns a unique ID back. Using that ID & GET API we could find the status of our job. Once it shows 'Completed' we could download the results. 
My question is - instead of us polling every time/periodically to know the status of our job, do Spatial services provide any kind of Webhook so that we will know once our job is complete? If not Webhook is there a workaround? Right now I submit the job; after ~2 hrs, another job polls for status and if complete, downloads the result.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Webhook capabilities available for the moment. I guess then, that the only option available is to retrieve regularly the status as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/spatial-data-services/geocode-dataflow-api/get-status-of-a-geocode-job